# Still waiting for that analytical badge

Tags: support, badges, analytical-badge

I went through all the steps, pressing the 'expand all' link, etc., and after five days I still have no badge. I've also read and followed all of the meta questions on this topic. Can someone please state definitively requirements for this badge?

Comment: Those are the requirements. Are you sure you clicked the "What if I need more help?" title? It's the very last one, and doesn't have a "show more" link - easy to miss.

Comment: @animuson I can't find a "What if I need more help?" section.

Comment: @irrelephant: It only exists on main sites, not on Meta (because it basically tells you to go to to Meta).

Comment: @animuson:  Wait a sec.  I have that badge here.  *You* have that badge here.  How did we go beyond the meta?

Comment: @Makoto Because Meta.SO is very special ;)

Comment: Huh, I always thought this badge only required clicking on the "show more" sections.

Comment: Well I finally got the badge after I clicked on "What if I need more help?" thanks @animuson.