# Require analytical badge before asking questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, site-faq, analytical-badge

Every day we have new users posting [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285287/how-to-create-a-checkbook-register-application-using-sql-and-c-sharp) (*10k required, or soon to be*). These are not questions that will ever help the site in any way and, as more and more of them show up, more and more time is spent by folks closing, deleting, down-voting, disparaging, what have you.

I think it would be reasonable to impose a requirement that they must visit the FAQ (and in fact earn the [analytical badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical)) before they can post a question. This is different from [other requirements that have been requested, such as minimum rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/require-users-to-earn-some-minimum-rep-before-asking-questions).

This is not a difficult badge to earn and does not seem to be a big imposition - and in fact *can* prevent users from having a negative first experience. No, it still won't guarantee that they actually *read* the thing, but it at least stresses the importance of understanding how the site works before firing away.

Comment: The analytical badge is actually [quite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144394/analytical-badge-plainly-not-working) [buggy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160434/still-waiting-for-that-analytical-badge) at times. It took me a few tries to actually get the badge even though I have read through everything twice.

Comment: The thing is you don't have to actually read the FAQ to get the analytical badge... You just have to click quick. Takes about 10 seconds... All this does is put a further impediment in front of good new users.

Comment: @ben yes, I agree, and I stated so in my question. It is not a big imposition and it at least makes people see that there is a FAQ and they *should* read it.

Comment: I can also read most of the important stuff in the [faq] without clicking the links, so it is possible to read it 100 times and know the basics by heart and I still wouldn't have the badge.

Comment: @Antony then there is a bug that needs to be fixed. I don't think that's a good excuse to not use the badge for something useful - if it's broken, fix it or get rid of it!

Comment: People who are opposed to this simple and logical tie-in, do you have a better answer to propose? The site is getting worse by the day. Just about every question is too localized or too open-ended to help anyone but the OP.

Comment: @psubsee2003 **You** can read; but most of the new users *won't*. The point here is to get them to read the FAQ.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO The fact that you have to [expand every section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/how-does-the-analytical-badge-work) to get the badge makes it very unhelpful in this case. I honestly read through the FAQ before I post my first question, but it took me weeks to figure out how to get the badge. Whereas those who post bad questions are usually the ones who don't bother to read anyway and would try to game the system so that they can get their question posted.

Comment: Very closely related: [Add "I have read the FAQ" check box to the Ask Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147201). While I sympathize, I don't really understand what this would add to/how it differs from the existing [click through advice for askers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84670/). It seems to me that discussing or suggesting additions to the contents of that page might be a better route than suggesting adding another box that needs to be checked off.

Comment: If this badge is required in order to post a question all it will do is cause people to click through all the links on the FAQ so they are able to post their question. Even if a user does read the FAQ that won't really stop all the poor questions that are being posted.

Comment: @Joe yes, I know that. Did you read the whole question?

Comment: @JoshCaswell We need to have them watch a video about what a quality answer is. Perhaps using the clockwork orange method. Jon Skeet could even narrate.

Comment: @Antony so maybe the buggy badge shouldn't be a part of this, but there should be some other way to ensure that the user has seen, specifically, the part about how to ask questions. You will never be able to force anyone to read anything, but you can make it so that they get some hint that it is important.

Comment: @AaronBertrand New users are already forced through the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), where they are required to acknowledge reading it before being able to proceed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I did read the whole question but I think what I posted is worth pointing out because having it required will not change anything and it will just put another barrier in front of a new user who is looking to ask a question. I would guess that a lot of new users that are not posting the bad questions are in fact reading the FAQ but they do not always expand every section and do not get the badge.

Comment: @FreshP: It's [been proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91447/rfc-stack-exchange-2-minute-intro).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm expecting something more than a high school Prezi presentation.

Comment: @Joe right, and that was already pointed out by ben and psubsee and Antony, and I already acknowledged in the post above that I understand that clicking on the links does not mean they actually read it. I think there has got to be a way to stress the importance of reading the FAQ before posting. What we're doing now is clearly not working.

Comment: Also closely related: [Why not show the FAQ on user sign up?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176777), [Can we get a "Welcome, check out our FAQ!" notification for new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143058)

Comment: @AaronBertrand the [about] page was a step in the right direction.  Would expanding on that be the idea you are looking for, maybe by including more details on why SO is different than a traditional forum, and/or adding some more FAQ related "what you can ask" and "what you can't ask" info, and some suggestions on creating good questions.

Comment: The analytical badge is no longer awarded: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq/183243#183243